# swift nsurlconnection fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, nsurlconnection

I am using the following piece of code to download
some xml data from my server

```
//Build & Request the Url
let url = NSURL(string: "http://sample.com")
let request: NSURLRequest  = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
var response: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSURLResponse?
>=nil
var error: NSErrorPointer = nil
var xmlData: NSData =  NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: response, error:nil)!
var err: NSError
```

It works as expected most of the time. But if I disconnect the internet
and close the app and open again when the internet is connected
it throws the fatal error

```
var xmlData: NSData =  NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: response, error:nil)!
```

This seems to be the "faulty" line.
Since this happens only after I disconnect/reconnect the internet
maybe I should refresh dhe NSURLCONNECTION or something, I don't know.
I am thinking this because since it works as expected most of the time
maybe after I disconnect the NSURLCONNECTION doesn't properly detect
that the device is reconnected.

Any help/suggestions would be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use question optional mark, because it can be nil

```
var xmlData: NSData? = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: response, error:nil)
```

or

```
var xmlData: NSData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: response, error:nil)?
```

or

```
var xmlData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: response, error:nil) as? NSData
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks.
Any idea if using https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLConnection/cancel

Would reset the connection?

Comment: cancel just for async methods

Comment: May I ask you one more thing please? The next line of code below that is:

xmlContent  = NSString(data: dataVal!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

and this throws an error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I have tried replacing ! with ? or removing either but none works.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! If I havent solved it until tomorrow I may ask you again if you will have time to respond :)

Answer (score 0):

Add nil coalescing

```
var xmlData: NSData? =  NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: response, error:nil) ?? nil
```

Comment: Any idea if using the .cancel() function
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURLConnection/cancel

Would fix the issue?

Comment: Your suggestion throws an error:
Cannot invoke >>> with an argument list of type (NSData, NilLiteralConvertible)

Comment: Nope, "Cancels an asynchronous load of a request."